# Visual studio core - how to deploy ASP .NET Core 2.2. to a folder?

Tags: deployment

in Visual studio core - how to deploy ASP .NET Core 2.2. to a folder?

I did not find such menu inside VS Code :(

please help

Thanks a lot in advance
Don

Answer (score 0):

you can use the command `dotnet publish -o <folder name>`